# how to use a compressed_sparse_row_graph and dijkstra with the BOOST graph library

Tags: c++, boost

Background: I am a hack, not a good programer by any means, FORTRAN is my language actually, need some help with this boost code.  I get a 'vector subscript out of range' error in line 779 of vector when I implement this.  Here is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated!

The program reads the edges from a file, builds a graph, then I would like to calculate the distance from one vertex to all other vertices.

The issue seems like it should be easy to resolve, but I am struggling, thanks!

-Jeff

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <utility>               
#include <algorithm>             
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/compressed_sparse_row_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_color_map.hpp> 

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>     
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;



int main()
{


long int num_nodes;
long int num_edges;
char *gfile ; //graph data file
char  buffer[128] ;
istringstream instream ;
gfile="grid.out";
ifstream infile( gfile, ios::in );
infile.getline(buffer, 128);
instream.clear() ;
instream.str(buffer) ;
instream >> num_nodes >> num_edges;

float wt;  // Allocate n ints and save ptr in a.
int num_arcs = num_edges;
int n1,n2;

  cout << "READING graph into C++ program from file grid.out";  cout << endl;cout << endl;  cout << endl;
  cout << "Found ";cout << num_nodes; cout << " nodes, and "; cout << num_edges; cout << " edges";cout  << endl;

     typedef std::pair < int, int > Edge;
     struct Edge_Cost
     {
         double weight;
     };

     struct vertex_data {
         boost::graph_traits<
             boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph< boost::directedS > >::vertex_descriptor p;
         double d;
     };

     typedef boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph<
         boost::directedS,
         vertex_data,
         Edge_Cost
     > graph_t;

     typedef boost::graph_traits < graph_t >::vertex_descriptor
         vertex_descriptor;
     graph_t* Graph;

     std::vector<vertex_descriptor> p;//path
     std::vector<double> d;    //distance

         int numb_edges                  = num_edges;
         Edge* edge_list                 = new Edge [numb_edges];
         Edge* ptr_edge_list             = edge_list;
         Edge_Cost* edge_weight_list     = new Edge_Cost[numb_edges];
         Edge_Cost* ptr_edge_weight_list = edge_weight_list;

    for (int i=0; i<num_edges; ++i)
    {
        //get a line from the file, vertex n1 is linked to vertex n2 by weight wt, but first vertex in file is 1 not 0, so -1


                //here is an example of the file:
                //grid.out:  first line is nvertex, nedges
//10  10
//1 2 0.296033428
//2 3 0.038954928
//3 4 0.080953663
//4 5 0.917876269
//5 6 0.026168687
//6 7 0.037261078
//7 8 0.409351058
//8 9 0.398426038
//9 10 0.942112529
//10 11 0.006422981

        infile.getline(buffer, 128);
        instream.clear() ;
            instream.str(buffer) ;
        instream >> n1 >> n2 >> wt;
        *ptr_edge_list++        = Edge(n1-1,n2-1);
        (ptr_edge_weight_list++)->weight =wt;
    }

Graph = new graph_t(boost::edges_are_unsorted,edge_list,ptr_edge_list,edge_weight_list,num_nodes);

    vertex_descriptor s = vertex(1,*Graph);

        //get one set of distances
    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_color_map
         (*Graph,s,
         boost::predecessor_map(&p[0]).
         distance_map(&d[0]).
         weight_map(boost::get(&Edge_Cost::weight, *Graph))
         );



return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"'vector subscript out of range' ..."_ Good starting point to learn how to debug your code. Launch the debugger, and step through line by line! (_"I am a hack, not a good programer"_ No you aren't, hackers should know how to write good programs in 1st place, but explore techniques getting over this)

Comment: Thanks, I do know how to do that (yeah, I'm only half a hack), still does not help, seems the graph is built correctly, number of nodes, edges, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The type Graph must be a model of Vertex List Graph and Incidence Graph. [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_color_map.html)

Seeing how http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/graph/doc/compressed_sparse_row.html#models shows:

> The `compressed_sparse_row_graph` class template models (i.e.,
>   implements the requirements of) many of the BGL graph concepts,
>   allowing it to be used with most of the BGL algorithms. In particular,
>   it models the following specific graph concepts:
>
> - Graph
> - **IncidenceGraph**
> - AdjacencyGraph
> - **VertexListGraph**
> - EdgeListGraph
> - PropertyGraph

This should be possible. Lemme try and postback in a moment

Ah. The question was a bit misleading. The error is that you don't reserve enough space in the distance and predecessor maps.

> The predecessor map records the edges in the minimum spanning tree. Upon completion of the algorithm, the edges (p[u],u) for all u in V are in the minimum spanning tree. If p[u] = u then u is either the source vertex or a vertex that is not reachable from the source. The PredecessorMap type must be a Read/Write Property Map `whose key and value types are the same as the vertex descriptor` type of the graph.

In other words, use a capacity high enough to address the highest vertex descriptor (11 in your sample)

> The shortest path weight from the source vertex start_vertex to each vertex in the graph graph is recorded in this property map. The shortest path weight is the sum of the edge weights along the shortest path. The type DistanceMap must be a model of Read/Write Property Map. The vertex descriptor type of the graph needs to be usable as the key type of the distance map

Here, the same applies.

#### Cleanup

Here's a cleanup of the code **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19429034a8143774)** that

- avoids `new` (and the missing `delete[]`)
- avoids unsafe buffers for `getline` by using std::getline
- combines `cout` statements in a single line
- sizes the predecessor/distance maps appropriately
- removes a spurious comment (`// Allocate n ints and save ptr in a.`?)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/compressed_sparse_row_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_color_map.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using namespace boost;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("input.txt", std::ios::in);

    long int num_nodes;
    long int num_edges;
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(infile, line);
        std::istringstream instream(line);
        instream >> num_nodes >> num_edges;
    }

    std::cout << "READING graph into C++ program from file" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Found " << num_nodes << " nodes, and " << num_edges << " edges" << std::endl;

    typedef std::pair < int, int > Edge;
    struct Edge_Cost
    {
        double weight;
    };

    struct vertex_data
    {
        boost::graph_traits<
        boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph< boost::directedS > >::vertex_descriptor p;
        double d;
    };

    typedef boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph<
    boost::directedS,
          vertex_data,
          Edge_Cost
          > graph_t;

    typedef boost::graph_traits < graph_t >::vertex_descriptor
    vertex_descriptor;

    std::vector<Edge> edge_list;
    std::vector<Edge_Cost> edge_weight_list;

    for(int i=0; i<num_edges; ++i)
    {
        float wt;
        int n1,n2;

        //get a line from the file, vertex n1 is linked to vertex n2 by weight
        //wt, but first vertex in file is 1 not 0, so -1

        std::string line;
        std::getline(infile, line);
        std::istringstream instream(line);
        instream >> n1 >> n2 >> wt;

        edge_list.emplace_back(n1-1, n2-1);
        edge_weight_list.push_back(Edge_Cost{wt});

        std::cout << "Read: " << n1 << " " << n2 << " " << wt << "\n";
    }

    graph_t Graph(boost::edges_are_unsorted,edge_list.begin(),edge_list.end(),&edge_weight_list[0],edge_list.size());

    vertex_descriptor s = vertex(1,Graph);
    std::vector<vertex_descriptor> p(11);//path
    std::vector<double> d(11);    //distance

    //get one set of distances
    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_color_map
        (Graph,s,
         boost::predecessor_map(&p[0]).
         distance_map(&d[0]).
         weight_map(boost::get(&Edge_Cost::weight, Graph))
        );
}
```

Comment: I've cleaned up the code a little bit, see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19429034a8143774)** (notably missing: input error handling)

Comment: Wow, thanks so much.  The question was misleading because I had no clue what the problem was, you are right, that solved it.  I see the silly error now.  Thanks for your time! It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is working but I cannot use your code, I have an older version of VS and the emplace_back and push_back functions are not working properly, not a big deal, my code seems to work, thank you so much again!

Comment: @Jeff, why don't you fix up those spots, instead? Your code was broken and leaking (and no, it wasn't leaking nudes). See [c++03 version **Live On Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d86428ccb40016e)

Comment: Yes I will!  Like I said I'm a hack, I don't even know where my code is leaking!  I really should just pay someone to do this for me (how much do you charge? ... just kidding ... I'm learning).  Honestly this is my first C++ program (first program in any C language for that matter).  I will certainly compare what you did with what I did to learn!  And I am installing vs2012 which is supposed to deal well with those vector operations, so I can learn those too ;) I am very grateful for your help, you have no idea ...

Comment: You're doing great for a first timer. Had you not come this far I would have vehemently recommended _against_ using Boost Graph Library. Yeah, I was pretty brief in the bullets (but it was hidden under _avoids `new` (and the missing `delete[]`)_).

Comment: honestly, i am not sure what to do here lol, i got things to work, life is good ... I cut the memory in half, I am happy, but it could be better lol, i cannot still run your code, the line 'edge_weight_list.push_back(Edge_cost{wt}); comes up with the error C2275: 'mailn::Edge_Cost' illegal use of this type as an expression', anyway, still, thank you bro!!!!

Comment: @Jeff Make sure you added that constructor _and_ it's no longer a local type. Local types cannot be involved in template instantiations in c++03